# Character from List in String

Tags: algorithm, string

Good morning,

I am ashamed of posting this question since I should be able to figure this alone, but at the moment I can't think of any better solutions...

Say I have a list `L` of characters, and a string `S`. I want to know if every character in `S` belongs to `L`, and the only solution I can't think of at the moment is the trivial

```
boolean Result = true
boolean Temp = false

for i from 1 to S.Length
    Temp <- false
    for j from 1 to A.Count
        if (S[i] == A[j]) Temp <- true

    Result = Result && Temp

return Result
```

Please note that I am not caring about optimization to *this* algorithm, which could easily be done, but instead for a *better* algorithm. Can anyone please help me figure out? Note also that most of the time `S.Length` is much bigger than `A.Count`. Finally, I don't want to use regexes.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Here iterating over the list of characters costs O(A.Count). You could store the characters in a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), thus you could determine if S[i] belongs to A in constant time provided the hash function is appropriately chosen.

So with a good hash function you would reduce the global cost from O(S.Length * A.Count) to O(S.Length).

If you're dealing with ASCII characters, then your hash table may be trivially reduced to an array of 128 elements, with identity as the "hash function". If you're dealing with Unicode characters, but your texts contain a majority of ASCII characters, then you may think of a variation of this.

Comment: Even considering Unicode, there are only 1114112 characters (0...0x10FFFF) (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32/UCS-4), so it's 1114112 bits... so 140kb. I think it's reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort alphabetically `L` and `S`, using quicksort for example.
Now you can compare character by character `L` and `S`, so your time will be `O(n1 log n1) (for sort of L) + O(n2 log n2) (for sort of S) + Max(n1, n2) (for comparing the two sorted strings character by character)` where `n1 = L.Length` and `n2 = S.Length` So given `n = Max(n1, n2)`, you should have a time `O(n log n)` (I hope) :-)

The exact implementation depends on how you want to handle multiple equal letters. If `L = "A"` and `S = "AA"`, does `S` match `L`?

Answer (score 0):

Could you just count the characters in S and L and then just compare counts?  This avoids the nested loop structure so I think this is O(N+M) rather than O(MN) (where M and N are the lengths of the string).

```
int[] Lcount = new int[256];
int[] Scount = new int[256];

for (int i=0;i<L.length;++i) {
  Lcount[L.charAt(i)]++;
}

for (int i=0;i<S.length;++i) {
  Scount[S.charAt(i)]++;
}

for (int i=0;i<256;i++) {
   // S doesn't have the characters in L so can't be a subset
   if (Scount[i] < Lcount[i]) {
      return false;
   }
}

return true;
```

The example above assumes ASCII representation of the characters, you could apply the same sort of idea using a hash table if the number of characters were bigger than ASCII (e.g. Unicode).